# ANSIBLE: Create an inventory of inventories?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'd like to know if it is possible to use a simple file to refer all my inventories path.

I already use a global inventory for all my development but nowaday i have a to use specific inventory for specific role in the same developement.

I know we can use : *-i my first inventory -i my second inventory.*

I just wanted to know if i can do it more "esthetic". Like use a simple file who contain all inventories path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ansible --version` to detect wich `ansible.cfg` is in use.

You will see some like :

> ```
> $ ansible --version 
> ansible 2.7.12
>   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
> ```

Edit `ansible.cfg` and add the following in the `defaults`  section :

`inventory      =  /path-to-folder-1,/path-to-folder-2`

Multiple folders are separated with comma ",".